# Java application to communicate with mysql server

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, servlets

I wanted to build a chat application with the following structure:

**Description:**

- Chat app to comunicate between computers with a server in the middle of the connection(with a database and a web service);

**Login process:**

1. The user1 inserts a username and a password;
2. The web service receives the login request;
3. The web service validates the login with the database;
4. The web service sends a response to the login request;

**Process:**

1. The user1 sends a message..
2. The web service receives the message and makes a new row on the database with the message associated with the id of the user1 and with the id of user2;
3. The user2 now as a new message associated with his ID;

**Question/Doubt part:**

I got to say **thank you**, if you read this all until here.

My question is, **what kind of web service should I use** so i can communicate properly with the sql database, i know it is a stupid question, but I'm new to this **web service** thing, and all the information I've found is unclear to me.

Thank you so much

Comment: you probably don't need the overhead of a mySQL, try an embedded java DB instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing it only for study purpose then I think you dont even need sql database.
You can use RMI technology to make a chat application.

If you want to use sql database as well then I guess you can use servlets to handle server side logic and client request. and through the servlets you can manage your database

Comment: Thank you man for your quick answer. I heard that servlets are only for broswer communication... Is that true? Because that's not what I want.

Comment: I can't... I'm new here, no reputation.

Comment: I'll save this link, and when i have enough reputation I'll upvote( promess)